# Appending child view to body / other element

Tags: ember.js

I'm building a popover/dropdown with Ember which essentially boils down to:

```
<div class="popover">
  <span {{action showPopover}}>Click</span>
  {{#if popoverShowing}}
    <div class="popover-body">The popover body</div>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

All works fine but I have other elements on the page which are absolutely positioned and due to them forming a new stacking context there's no way I can make the popover be displayed above them.

If this were plain old Javascript, I'd append the popover to the body much like how [Bootstrap does with the `container` option](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) but we don't have that level of control in Ember AFAICT.

The only solution I can think of is to use an `{{outlet}}` in the application template and render to that, but that means for every popover/dropdown I have to split the contents out to a different view/template/controller and have an action in the router which seems rather over-complicated!

Can anyone think of a better option?

Comment: hey @rlivsey, have you figured out a solid solution for that problem? I have a similar use case and don´t know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that seems to work is to detach the body element on `didInsertElement` and then manually destroy on `willDestroyElement`:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  Ember.$("body").append(this.$())
},

willDestroyElement: function() {
  this.$().remove()
}
```

This appears to work fine, but there are probably bugs lurking!